# WMS GeoServer request with elevation range

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am checking multidimensional requests (time and elevation) using GeoServer WMS.

Now I am triying mutidimensional requests (time and elevation) within a range.

According to [1](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/wxs_ranges.html) elevation range can be requested in WCS services using a subset.

Can requests with elevation range be done in WMS?

This is an example of one of my requests but requested elevation data does not appear, only the default data:

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/First_test_wms/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=First_test_wms%3Ameteo_stations_elevation&bbox=-983582.0%2C3132430.0%&width=768&height=637&srs=EPSG%3A25830&format=application/openlayers&subset=http://www.opengis.net/def/axis/OGC/0/elevation(20,150)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in making WMS requests then you should read the [WMS spec](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416) not the WCS spec.

Then looking in Annex C you would see that you specify elevations as a number or range.

```
elevation=20
```

or (a range)

```
elevation=20/150
```

or (a range with a step)

```
 elevation=20/150/10
```